# Using Powershell to get a vm's own name

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

The short question is; can a VM use powershell to get its own name?

I have an environment where I have 12 identical sets of VMs.  Each set has one jump server, and the naming convention is ##_APP_SET#, where ## is a corresponding NAT device, and SET# tells me the set of VMs.

On this APP VM, I have created a menu that uses an account on the external vCenter to turn the VMs in the set on and off.  So from within the VM, it is connecting to its parent vCenter and running an action on another VM in the set.  The problem is that I have the VM names hard coded in the script.  For example, if I'm on 01_APP_SET1, I have a bunch of entries for 01_MACHINENAME_SET1, and on 02_APP_SET2, I have entries for 02_MACHINENAME_SET2, etc.

I am currently managing 12 different scripts on the 12 different APP VMs.  I am hoping to make the script more general where the VM calls a get-vm on itself and parses out the preceding ## and trailing SET#, but not having much luck beyond getting a list of systems called APP with get-vm *APP*.

I'm thinking the best way to tackle this would be to give each APP VM a hostname matching its name in vCenter, then parsing out the information that way.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any sort of identifiable information that is unique to the APP VM such as a external facing IP to be able to log in to outside of the private networking for the Set?

Perhaps something like this would be helpful:
`$ip = (ipconfig | Select-String "IPv4 Address" | Select-String "192.168.1").Line.Replace("IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :","")
$vm = get-vm | ?{$_.Guest.IPAddress -like $ip}`

Comment: That's actually one of the challenges.  They all have the same IP.  Each set is in it's own isolated network.  Aside from the VM names, the images are identical.  They are also supposed to all have the same hostname, but I'm thinking I can give them all hostnames matching the VM name and then create a host file entry as an alias.

Comment: If you are able to rename the machines to match their VM name, you could use $compname = $env:computername, then Get-VM $compname.

Answer (score 0):

Or group the VMs with [tags](http://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2013/12/using-tags-with-powercli.html) in VC and use [Invoke-VMScript](http://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2013/12/using-tags-with-powercli.html) to poke around other guests as necessary.